# Mysql- Query items that are up to only 2nd level in hierarchy

Tags: php, mysql, join, relational-database

I have a categories table that I resolved into another table `categories_to_categories` for `many-to-many` relation.
Now I want to select only those categories which have

1. Either parent_id =0
2. Either their parent's parent_id =0

Here is my [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6d82/3), In the result set, I have 2 problems,

1. Results are duplicating
2. Customized Shirts category shouldn't be there as it already have a parent and its parent doesn't have `parent_id =0`

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `status` enum('ACTIVE','INACTIVE') DEFAULT 'ACTIVE',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `banner_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `franchise_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `categories_uuid_uindex` (`uuid`)
);



INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES (1,'xyz','Printing','test','ACTIVE','2016-11-29 13:54:15','2016-11-29 13:54:18',NULL,3),(2,'abc','Digital','test','ACTIVE','2016-11-29 14:33:48','2016-11-29 14:33:53',NULL,3),(3,'def','Video','test','ACTIVE','2016-11-29 14:34:25','2016-11-29 14:34:29',NULL,3),(4,'s','Merchandise printing','test','ACTIVE','2016-11-29 14:35:02','2016-11-29 14:35:04',NULL,3),(5,'4','D/C','test','ACTIVE','2016-11-29 14:35:24','2016-11-29 14:35:27',NULL,3),(6,'2','Goods','test','ACTIVE','2016-11-29 14:35:49','2016-11-29 14:35:51',NULL,3),(8,'5','B/A Templates','test','ACTIVE','2016-11-29 14:36:26','2016-11-29 14:36:28',NULL,3),(9,'gggg','Customized Shirts','test','ACTIVE','2016-11-29 14:37:00','2016-11-29 14:37:01',NULL,3);



CREATE TABLE `categories_to_categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);



INSERT INTO `categories_to_categories` VALUES (1,1,0,'2016-11-29 13:54:56','2016-11-29 13:54:59'),(2,2,0,'2016-11-29 14:38:10','2016-11-29 14:38:17'),(3,3,0,'2016-11-29 14:38:28','2016-11-29 14:38:29'),(4,4,1,'2016-11-29 14:38:48','2016-11-29 14:38:51'),(5,5,2,'2016-11-29 14:39:28','2016-11-29 14:39:30'),(6,6,0,'2016-11-29 14:39:41','2016-11-29 14:39:43'),(7,4,6,'2016-11-29 14:39:52','2016-11-29 14:39:55'),(8,7,1,'2016-11-29 14:40:11','2016-11-29 14:40:17'),(9,8,4,'2016-11-29 14:40:29','2016-11-29 14:40:32'),(10,9,2,'2016-11-29 14:40:40','2016-11-29 14:40:42');
```

Query that isn't working:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM CATEGORIES                     A
 INNER JOIN CATEGORIES_TO_CATEGORIES  B
  ON A.ID = B.ID
 AND B.PARENT_ID = 0
  OR (SELECT PARENT_ID
        FROM CATEGORIES_TO_CATEGORIES
       WHERE ID = B.PARENT_ID
     ) = 0 ;
```

Comment: Please add all necessary info directly into the question.

Comment: Actually, 'Customized Shirts' should be in the result set - it has only one parent node 'Digital' which is root category (parent_id = 0)

Comment: added code from sql fiddle

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions is to use union of root categories and their children:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name FROM categories c 
WHERE c.id IN (
  SELECT cc.category_id FROM categories_to_categories cc 
  WHERE cc.parent_id = 0 

  UNION

  SELECT pc.category_id FROM categories_to_categories cc 
  LEFT JOIN categories_to_categories pc ON cc.category_id = pc.parent_id 
  WHERE cc.parent_id = 0 
)
ORDER BY c.id;
```

Result of this query will be list of root categories / subcategories without duplicates ('Merchandise printing' is child node for both 'Printing' and 'Goods', but in the result set it appears only once):

```
+----+----------------------+
| id | name                 |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | Printing             |
|  2 | Digital              |
|  3 | Video                |
|  4 | Merchandise printing |
|  5 | D/C                  |
|  6 | Goods                |
|  9 | Customized Shirts    |
+----+----------------------+
```